# How to create setup from obfuscated outlook addin in c# VS2017

Tags: c#, .net, outlook-addin, crypto-obfuscator

I am using Click One installation (publish).
I am having issue with creating installer from obfuscated Outlook addin.
Does anyone have step by step tutorial how can I create installer for client from obfuscated dll?

I tried to use InstallShield Limited Edition, but it works only with earlier versions of VS.

Also, I tried to use MageUi to replace dll with obfuscated. 
But I got error when tried to run installer.

Maybe I should use wix installer?
Obfuscator I use is Crypto Obfuscator.

I use VS2017 Community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem with MageUI tool.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Inno Setup to create the installer and Smart Assembly to obfuscate the DLL.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, do you have link for tutorial?